# OpenCV Principal Component Analysis terminology - what actually is a 'sample'?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, pca, principal-components

I'm working with Principal Component Analysis ([PCA](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#pca)) in openCV. The constructor inputs for the case I'm interested in are:

```
PCA(InputArray data, InputArray mean, int flags, double retainedVariance);
```

Regarding the InputArray 'data' the documents state the appropriate flags should be:

> **CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW** indicates that the input samples are stored as
>   matrix rows.
>   **CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL** indicates that the input samples are
>   stored as matrix columns.

My question pertains to the use of the term 'samples' in that I'm not sure what a sample is in this context.

For example let's say I have **4** sets of data and for the sake of illustration let's label them A-D. Now each set A through D has **8** elements. They are then set up in the Mat variable I'll use as InputArray as follows:

[image]

The question is, which is it:

- **My *sets* are samples?**
- **My *data elements* are samples?**

Another way of asking:

- **Do I have 4 samples (CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL)**
- **Or do I have 4 sets of 8 samples (CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW)**

?

As a *guess*, I'd choose **CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL**  (i.e. I have 4 samples) - but that's just where my head is at...  Until I learn the correct terminology it seems the word 'sample' could apply to either reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh...

So the answer was found by reversing the logic behind the documentation for the PCA::project step...

```
Mat PCA::project(InputArray vec)
```

> vec – input vector(s); must have the same dimensionality and the same
>   layout as the input data used at PCA phase, that is, if
>   CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW are specified, then vec.cols==data.cols (vector
>   dimensionality)

i.e. **'sample' is equivalent to 'set', and the elements are the 'dimension'.**

(and my guess was correct :)